# InfluxDB Sum Messages per hour

Tags: influxdb

I am writing to a InfluxDB counters per time period (the delta between each submission for the new seen messages of that type). I would like to combine the total count of messages over a time period to give messages per hour (or other time periods).

I have the below query, and using `https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/reference/flux/stdlib/built-in/transformations/aggregates/sum/`:

```
from(bucket: "ServiceStats")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "PolygonIoStream")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "aggregatesCounter" or r["_field"] == "quotesCounter" or r["_field"] == "statusesCounter" or r["_field"] == "tradesCounter")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> Sum()
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

However i get the error `runtime error @6:6-6:74: aggregateWindow: missing time column "_time"`

I will be honest, this as my first query I have quickly gotten out of my depth - pointers much appreciated.